# NSMutableDictionary not initializing if certain characters included

Tags: php, ios, special-characters, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to create an NSMutableDictionary and populate it with forum posts queried from my website.  Super-simple code, nothing but...

```
_postBodies = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlBodiesSource]];
```

...pulling from a PHP/MySQL-generated plist file, and it usually works great.  Thing is, if any of the posts include certain characters, such as non-English letters or HTML symbols and the like, the whole thing fails to initialize altogether.  I've tracked it in the debugger line-by-line, and I can literally watch it work with 34 posts (or whatever) in the source file, but add that 35th post with the weird characters to the plist and the whole thing fails to initialize.

Is there a way around this?  Some method for stripping out or escaping characters that would be problematic for an NSMutableDictionary?  Or could they be tripping up my plist file perhaps, and the Dictionary is working fine?

For example, check out [this plist source file](http://edgeworksent.com/ios_thread_bodies.php?postthreadid=2272).  It's only three posts long, and the last one is the problem.  Exclude that post, the whole thing works; include it and the NSMutableDictionary fails to populate at all.  It seems pretty normal, except that it has some tabs and some O's with circumflexes on them.

```
<key>2</key>
<string>Wow, SquattingB.  I know I'm melodramatic, but what's with you?  lol.  Yeah, it's a shame that all the cool people congregated here just to watch the codex, only to have the series end and leave everyone dumbstruck as to what to do.  (It was that good, nothing else has the same appeal)  Hopefully this forum will remain as cool as it has been up to the point when the creators get out of college.  Then maybe we can see whether they have awesome news of what is next for the series and the forum or if they just boot us back to HBO.  lol.But what is a forum?Dictionary   forum |?fôr?m| noun ( pl. forums ) 1 a place, meeting, or medium where ideas and views on a particular issue can be exchanged : it will be a forum for consumers to exchange their views on medical research. 2 a court or tribunal. 3 ( pl. fora |?fôr?|) (in an ancient Roman city) a public square or marketplace used for judicial and other business. ORIGIN late Middle English (sense 3) : from Latin, literally ‘what is out of doors,’ originally denoting an enclosure surrounding a house; related to fores ‘(outside) door.’ Sense 1 dates from the mid 18th cent.That's what I thought.  So the people are what make it great, yes?  And I'm sure the patrons aren't leaving anytime soon, so we're in pretty good standing as to what will become of the forum.  For now, anyway.</string>
```

Has anyone experienced this before, or can anyone offer any advice?  I'm just getting started so simpler solutions would be appreciated, but I'd love any insight you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you checking the PList text encoding? Remember that iOS programming is done in UTF-8.

I assume (as the question is marked with the PHP tag), that the URL you are retrieving works with PHP. Did you try encoding the text using **utf8_encode()**?

Another way could be using JSON. **json_encode()** in PHP automatically translates weird characters to its UTF-8 hex-representation (**\x{NUMBER}**). Also, you could try using **htmlspecialchars()**.

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome, the **utf8_encode()** seems to have worked.  Thanks!